# jHipster - simplify generation of the new APP if the DB already exists

Tags: jhipster, spring-roo

does any tool exist that can simplify generation of the new APP if the DB already exists? I can create JDL file for new app manually base on existing DB - but I prefer to automate the process. This DB is part of old Spring Roo app.

Thank you.

Comment: I dont think like exists for now. Better you start creating the JDL file.

Comment: I have ended up with this approach. There is no silver bullet yet.

Answer (score 1):

The spring Roo 1.x version provides the "Database Reverse Engineering" functionality. This add-on allows you to create an application tier of JPA 2.0 entities based on the tables in your database. DBRE will also incrementally maintain your application tier if you add or remove tables and columns.

After generate the entities, you could execute the necessary `web mvc` commands to generate the complete application.

However, remember that the Spring Roo 1.x is not beeing maintained, because uses old technologies.

See more about the DBRE process here:

http://docs.spring.io/spring-roo/reference/html/base-dbre.html

Hope it helps,

Comment: Thank you, But I need jHipster app with Angular UI to be generated.

Answer (score 1):

There's a JHipster module that is being developed for this purpose: https://github.com/bastienmichaux/generator-jhipster-db-helper

It is probably not ready yet but could be a good start.